# Call a method from Static Class passing Type of Dynamic variable with Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, static-methods

How can i call a method from a static class passing a type of dynamic in generic.
Here is my static class:

```
public static class Log<T>
{
    private readonly static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T));

    public static void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        Logger.Info(message);
    }
}
```

I want to call LogInfo like this:

```
Log<myObject.GetType()>.LogInfo("Some String");
```

My question is about how to pass a type of myObject in Generic, because the type of this object is dynamic.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "passing a type of dynamic in generic".

Comment: You have an interface named `ILog` and a class named `Log` that doesn't implement `ILog`. I'd advise against that.

Comment: @Jason I will review that, thanks...

Comment: @Jason What you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to call LogInfo like this:

```
Log<myObject.GetType()>.LogInfo("Some String");
```

Why? Why don't you just do this:

```
public static class Log {
     private static readonly Dictionary<Type, ILog> loggers =
         new Dictionary<Type, ILog>();

     public static void LogInfo(Type type, string message) {
          var logger = Log.GetLoggerForType(type);
          logger.Info(message);
     }

     public static void LogInfo<T>(string message) {
          LogInfo(typeof(T), message);
     }

     private static ILog GetLoggerForType(Type type) {
          ILog logger;
          if(!loggers.TryGetValue(type, out logger)) {
               logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
               loggers.Add(type, logger);
          }
          return logger;
     }
}
```

Note that this is not, Not, NOT thread safe. I wanted to communicate the idea.

Then:

```
Log<myObject.GetType()>.LogInfo("Some String");
```

can be replaced by

```
Log.LogInfo(myObject.GetType(), "Some String");
```

or you can even go one step further and add an overload that allows you to say

```
Log.LogInfo(myObject, "Some String");
```

(just call `object.GetType` in `LogInfo`).